# How to use chown command in PHP?

Tags: php, chmod, shell-exec, chown

I want the user to be able to read and edit files in the test folder, these files are always created by a software with read-only properties.

I can't use the chown command manually, so I need a chown command that can work in PHP before the user's read and write commands automatically.

Manual ok:

```
root@vultr: chown -R nginx /var/www/html/test //run ok, All files in the test folder can be read and written

root@vultr:~# /var/www/html/test/test.sh //run ok, the test.sh file contains the "chown -R nginx command /var/www/html/test"
```

My php code but not working

```
shell_exec('./test.sh'); 

chown('file_webuser', 'nginx');
```

Comment: did you also use `chmod` to change file permissions?

Comment: I am sure you can run the command directly with exec() function in PHP so it will be exec("chown -R nginx /var/www/html/test");

Comment: Only when using the chown command successfully will chmod work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chown (change owner) won't work for non-root user. What you really need to do is to grant the user (I assume it's a `nginx`) full permissions to files.

It can be achieved in few ways. The most secure way is to run PHP (I'm guessing PHP is running as a PHP-FPM) as a `nginx` user by editing params `user` and `group` in your `php-fpm.conf` file and restarting the PHP service.
In such case, the owner of files will be the same, so no file permission manipulation is needed. You'll need to change ownership of all files generated/uploaded by PHP to nginx once (using root user and chown command).

The second solution is to add the user who's running PHP-FPM to the same group as the nginx user and modify `umask` so the files are accessible to a group. Let's say that the group would be `www-data` (you have to add `nginx` user and the PHP-FPM process owner to that group, for example with `usermod` command, and edit your `php-fpm.conf`: set `group` to `www-data`). Then in your PHP scripts use `umask` function to allow all members of group to have full access to files: `umask(0007);`.

The third, least secure way is to give full access to your files for all users in the system. Use `umask` function in your PHP file to achieve this: `umask(0000);`

Answer (score 0):

this is because the `root` user probably has privileges to manipulate these files created by Nginx or etc.
if PHP is not the owner of that files you can put it on the authorized group that they have desired access to.

Answer (score -1):

Use the exec() in PHP so your code will look like:

```
exec("chown -R nginx /var/www/html/test");
```

Comment: This command i tried but not working, output is blank

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php it means it was executed successfully. According to PHP doc it is meant to return false when it fails. You will need to attach output parameter if you need a response.